# What's the proper way to handle a github script dependency in a CRAN package?

Tags: r, github, dependency-management, cran

There's a [**great R script** on Github to build correlation heatmaps](https://github.com/briatte/ggcorr) via ggplot2 (doesn't matter, just wanted to do the hat tip).

This script is a function, but it's not on CRAN (as such), and not even a package.
(It *is* be *part* of an upstream CRAN package, but crucial bugfixes in the script don't seem to make it to the upstream repo, let alone CRAN. Without the bugfixes, it's unusable.).

This function is only used internally by my package, and never directly exposed to users.

What's the proper way to use this script in my package?

I'd like to:

- properly recognize the script's authors work
- have this pass CRAN (obviously)
- be able to easily merge in upstream changes (from the *script*)
- script should be sourced (or whatever) on `library(mypkg)`, so that's ready to go and not remote-sourced via the internet anytime someone uses the function (that would be bad).

I was thinking of just copy/pasting the file, but a) recognition, and b) *there has to be a better way*.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the author to get them to add a `LICENSE` file to their repo? Copyright is solely to the owner w/o an explicit license, so you unfortunately can't just copy/paste the code. Try filling an issue with a request to include the code in your package, then give the author credit in the Authors @ R part of the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: yup, done - > https://github.com/briatte/ggcorr/issues/6
Thanks, @hrbrmstr

A previous (buggy) version of the same script *is* on CRAN and properly licensed, so I am guessing the copyright won't be the issue here. (You're right, of course).

I was wondering what might technically be the best way to do this ...

Comment: The best way to share code is to wrap it in a package. Same suggestion to @hrbrmstr but I think it is better to wrap the code in a new package.

Comment: If the code was already on CRAN, it's still on CRAN (in the archive), and will have a license attached to it. You can't relicense the code, but you can just copy it into your own package (sounds like you just need to create a non-exported function) as long as you retain the license and attribute authorship per the terms of the license. The whole point of FOSS is to make it easy to reuse code, so that's all you're doing here (with the CRAN code, not the copyrighted Github code).

Comment: I've just installed GGally from CRAN and it seems to be live and have a ggcorr function. What's the issue?

Comment: @NickK some crucial bugfixes don't seem to make it upstream to GGally and then CRAN: https://github.com/briatte/ggcorr/issues/1

Comment: @maxheld in which case the advice above seems entirely appropriate. However, since GGally is under GPL 2/3, my understanding is that any derivative work would also necessarily be GPL (see for example http://www.law.washington.edu/lta/swp/law/derivative.html) though I am not a lawyer.

Comment: @NickK I believe because R code will be distributed as source, you can retain GPL for this code but license the rest of the package however you want. The concern about licensing derivative works really only becomes an issue for binaries released without source code, which is something of a non-issue in the R world. (But I am also not a lawyer.)

Comment: @Thomas that wasn't my point, more that the specific ggcorr function which was originally released under the GPL is still therefore under GPL and can be used in the new package (with appropriate attribution and licensing). That specific function would again remain under GPL but I agree as I understand it that the rest of the package could potentially be under a different licence. In any case, perhaps the optimum solution would be for the new commits to ggcorr to be merged upstream into GGally by the package maintainer.